# Dim/Hide rest of map around country with leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to dim or hide the "rest of the world" except one country on a standard leaflet.js map? Mabye overlay out with some kind of "inverted polygon" with the contours of the country? Any code examples or links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding @tmcw's answer ...

The secret is to draw a polygon using the property described in http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon

> You can also create a polygon with holes by passing an array of arrays
>   of latlngs, with the first latlngs array representing the exterior
>   ring while the remaining represent the holes inside.

The first polygon will be a rectangle as big as the map itself, the hole will be the country you want to highlight.

```
L.polygon( [outerBoundsLatLngs, latLngs] );
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/1yaqtx9u/

Comment: The mask effect falls over when panning around as it seems to wait for the tiles to load before masking them. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I just noticed that clipping occurs with the L.Mask technique (the one I'm reffering to above) but not with leaflet-maskcanvas (check the demo http://domoritz.de/vbb-coverage/). I will try and understand how they do that.

Comment: http://geojson.io (tool: draw a polygone). When you close the shape, you'll be able to copy/paste the value (in the right view)

Answer (score 2):

See the [leaflet-maskcanvas](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas) and [L.Mask](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Mask/blob/master/L.Mask.js) plugins