# Create a custom map for specific states

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, maps, interactive

I'm trying to create an interactive custom map for a specific Brazilian state. I was able to create a map using the Leaflet Javascript library that highlighted the specific state(Paraná) and the cities in blue color. However, I would like to create a map containing only the Paraná's information. You can check the code below. Is possible to do that? Is there a better library?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<<script>
    // Inicializar o mapa
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-24.5, -51.5], 7);
  
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© Leaflet'
    }).addTo(map);
  
    var cities = [
      { name: 'Curitiba', location: [-25.4284, -49.2733] },
      { name: 'Londrina', location: [-23.3045, -51.1696] },
      { name: 'Maringá', location: [-23.4205, -51.9332] }
    ];
  
    cities.forEach(function(city) {
      var marker = L.marker(city.location).addTo(map);
      marker.bindPopup(city.name); 
    });
    
    fetch('assets/maps/br_pr.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        L.geoJSON(data, {
            style: {
            color: 'blue',  
            weight: 2,       
            fillOpacity: 0.2 
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    });

</script>
  
</html>
```

I have been trying to use the Leaflet library, as well as the D3 and Mapael libraries, but without success. I have tried to change the color of the other areas of the map in Leaflet, but it didn't help me. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652189/dim-hide-rest-of-map-around-country-with-leaflet-js